# Ionic 2 - Hide tabs on sub-pages

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have on my ionicbootstrap config:

```
{
   mode: 'md',
   tabsHideOnSubPages: true
}
```

On my settings, but on some sub-pages the tabs are showing. This seems a random behaviour.
Is this the right way of doing this?

ionic : 2.0.0@beta.11

Thanks
Artur

#

EDIT:

I'm using this fix to make the tabs go away:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.show-tabbar');
    if (tabs !== null) {
        Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
            tabs[key].style.transform = 'translateY(56px)';
        });
    } // end if
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.show-tabbar');
    if (tabs !== null) {
        Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
            tabs[key].style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
        });
    } // end if
}
```

But have to be a bad way. Any simple way of doing this?

Comment: Did you ever get resolution on this? I want to stop my tabs from hiding on subpages. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question with a fix, but still looking for a better solution... 
Which version of Ionic are you using @rashadb?

Comment: I'm using Ionic2.2.1. I had the opposite problem. I don't know if this will be helpful but you can see the resolution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841654/ionic2-tabs-disappear-whenever-i-push-a-new-page-component-with-navctrl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2017 Answer**

Based on the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/), you just simply need to add `tabsHideOnSubPages: true` to your app Ionic config like so:

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent, {
    tabsHideOnSubPages: true
  })
]
```